# How to Collapse a List of Labels | Python

Tags: python, list, networking, labeling

So I realize this is both a theoretical question and a coding question, but say if I have a list of 10 labels (x1, x2,...,x10) and their corresponding "location" vectors (v1, v2, ..., v10).

I want to collapse them based on their L2-norm distance from each other. For example, if v1 is close to v10, then relabel all x10's as x1's and so on.

So the end result could hypothetically look like the new labels: (x1, x3, x7, x8). Is there a way to smartly just make this into (x1', x2', x3', x4')?, so that people don't get confused and assume the new labels are the same.

Given: 
labels = vector of Nx1 that has all the labels (1,2,3...,10)

Example Code:

```
epsilon = 0.2  # defines distance
change = [] # initialize vector of labels to change

# matrix is NxN matrix of the pairwise distances between all our vectors (v1,..,v10)
for i in range(0, distancematrix): 
    for j in range(0, distancematrix):
        # add all pairs of labels that are "close", so that we may relabel
        if i!=j and distancematrix[i, j] < epsilon:
            change.append((i,j))
```

This will produce a list of pairs that I want to relabel. Is there a smart way of rewriting 'labels', so that it merges all the pairs I want to merge AND keeps the labels that were not part of any merge. Then reorganizes it to go from (1,2,3,4), if I merge 6 pairs of numbers (10-6 = 4).

Thank you. I realize this is somewhat of a weird problem, so if you have questions please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

This does the job actually for me.

```
# creates a list of numbers from 0 to the length of your newlabels vector
changeto = [i for i in range(0, len(np.unique(newlabels)))]

# get the unique values of your newlabels (e.g. 0, 3, 4, 5, 10)
currentlabels = np.unique(newlabels)

# change all your labels to your new mapping (e.g. 0 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 2, etc.)
for i in range(0, len(changeto)):
    if currentlabels[i] != changeto[i]:
        # change the 'states' in newlabels to new label
        newlabels = [changeto[i] if x==currentlabels[i] else x for x in newlabels]
```

Maybe it's not pretty, but you map your new labels onto the line 0, 1, 2,...x, where x is the length of your new condensed label vector.

Answer (score -1):

What if a label is not involved in any merge?  Do you want to keep the original label?  If so, what if that label is outside the new range?

Overall, I think that this is simply generating new labels given only the quantity of labels:

```
new_label_list = ["x"+str(n+1)+"'" for n in range(len(change))]
```

For change of length 4, this gives you
["x1'", "x2'", "x3'", "x4'"]

Do you see how the new label is built?

```
leading "x"
string version of the index, 1 .. length
trailing prime character
```

Comment: yes I do want to keep the original label if it was not involved in a merge and if the label is outside the new range, I want to condense it. Say I end up with labels (1, 3, 4, 5), I want to make it labels_new (1,2,3,4), but programmatically of course.

Comment: My question is about the form of the labels.  For instance, if your merged labels are ["x1", "x3", "x4", "x5"], do you want the new set to only move the x5 label, as in ["x1", "x2-prime", "x3", "x4"] ?  This is a little more involved.